# numpy array concatenate: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"

Tags: python, numpy

How to concatenate these `numpy` arrays?

first `np.array` with a shape `(5,4)`

```
[[  6487    400 489580      0]
 [  6488    401 492994      0]
 [  6491    408 489247      0]
 [  6491    408 489247      0]
 [  6492    402 499013      0]]
```

second `np.array` with a shape `(5,)`

```
[  16.   15.   12.  12.  17. ]
```

final result should be

```
[[  6487    400    489580    0   16]
 [  6488    401    492994    0   15]
 [  6491    408    489247    0   12]
 [  6491    408    489247    0   12]
 [  6492    402    499013    0   17]]
```

I tried `np.concatenate([array1, array2])`
but i get this error

`ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions`

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: How the heck is that second array supposed to have shape `(1,)`? Is there some sort of weird thing with object arrays going on here?

Comment: That is what i got when i run array2.shape

Comment: Then your array is seriously messed up in some way, and you need to figure out what's going on.

Comment: just before that i run this `array2 = np.array(np.round(data[:,0]/20))`

Answer (score 50, accepted):

To use `np.concatenate`, we need to extend the second array to `2D` and then concatenate along `axis=1` -

```
np.concatenate((a,b[:,None]),axis=1)
```

Alternatively, we can use `np.column_stack` that takes care of it -

```
np.column_stack((a,b))
```

Sample run -

```
In [84]: a
Out[84]: 
array([[54, 30, 55, 12],
       [64, 94, 50, 72],
       [67, 31, 56, 43],
       [26, 58, 35, 14],
       [97, 76, 84, 52]])

In [85]: b
Out[85]: array([56, 70, 43, 19, 16])

In [86]: np.concatenate((a,b[:,None]),axis=1)
Out[86]: 
array([[54, 30, 55, 12, 56],
       [64, 94, 50, 72, 70],
       [67, 31, 56, 43, 43],
       [26, 58, 35, 14, 19],
       [97, 76, 84, 52, 16]])
```

If `b` is such that its a `1D` array of `dtype=object` with a shape of `(1,)`, most probably all of the data is contained in the only element in it, we need to *flatten* it out before concatenating. For that purpose, we can use `np.concatenate` on it too. Here's a sample run to make the point clear -

```
In [118]: a
Out[118]: 
array([[54, 30, 55, 12],
       [64, 94, 50, 72],
       [67, 31, 56, 43],
       [26, 58, 35, 14],
       [97, 76, 84, 52]])

In [119]: b
Out[119]: array([array([30, 41, 76, 13, 69])], dtype=object)

In [120]: b.shape
Out[120]: (1,)

In [121]: np.concatenate((a,np.concatenate(b)[:,None]),axis=1)
Out[121]: 
array([[54, 30, 55, 12, 30],
       [64, 94, 50, 72, 41],
       [67, 31, 56, 43, 76],
       [26, 58, 35, 14, 13],
       [97, 76, 84, 52, 69]])
```

Comment: The b[:, None] notation is great, but it might also be worth mentioning b.reshape()

Comment: @PaulPanzer That's worth a new post! Consider posting it.

Comment: the shape of the second was because of this `array2 = np.array(np.round(data[:,0]/20))` i fixed with `array2 = np.array(np.round(data[:,0]/20)).astype(int)`

Answer (score 4):

There's also `np.c_`

```
>>> a = np.arange(20).reshape(5, 4)
>>> b = np.arange(-1, -6, -1)
>>> a
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3],
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7],
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11],
       [12, 13, 14, 15],
       [16, 17, 18, 19]])                                                                                                                                   
>>> b                                                                                                                                                       
array([-1, -2, -3, -4, -5])                                                                                                                                 
>>> np.c_[a, b]
array([[ 0,  1,  2,  3, -1],          
       [ 4,  5,  6,  7, -2],                       
       [ 8,  9, 10, 11, -3],                      
       [12, 13, 14, 15, -4],                                
       [16, 17, 18, 19, -5]])
```

Comment: Dare you to decode this one: `np.r_['1,2,0', a, -1:-6:-1]` :)

Comment: I wonder if `np.c_` can always substitute for `np.column_stack`?

Comment: @hpaulj Looks like it to me, but I'm not that familiar with `np.column_stack`. It is basically a 2d `concatenate` that special cases 1d inputs, right?

Answer (score 2):

You can do something like this.

```
import numpy as np

x = np.random.randint(100, size=(5, 4))
y = [16, 15, 12, 12, 17]

print(x)

val = np.concatenate((x,np.reshape(y,(x.shape[0],1))),axis=1)
print(val)
```

This outputs:

```
[[32 37 35 53]
 [64 23 95 76]
 [17 76 11 30]
 [35 42  6 80]
 [61 88  7 56]]

[[32 37 35 53 16]
 [64 23 95 76 15]
 [17 76 11 30 12]
 [35 42  6 80 12]
 [61 88  7 56 17]]
```

Answer (score 0):

It is not related to the original question.
But it can be useful when adding columns vertically in a loop.

```
a = np.empty([0,1], dtype=float) 
b = np.array([[6487, 400, 489.580],
              [6488, 401, 492.994],
              [6491, 408, 489.247],
              [6491, 408, 489.247],
              [6492, 402, 499.013]])

for c in range(0, 3):
    col = b[:, c]
    col = col.reshape(len(col),1)
    a = np.vstack((a, col))

print(a)

----------------------------------------------
Output:
[[6487.   ]
 [6488.   ]
 [6491.   ]
 [6491.   ]
 [6492.   ]
 [ 400.   ]
 [ 401.   ]
 [ 408.   ]
 [ 408.   ]
 [ 402.   ]
 [ 489.58 ]
 [ 492.994]
 [ 489.247]
 [ 489.247]
 [ 499.013]]
```