# Numpy append does not allow concatenation

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Also here are a lot of similar questions around, and one of the best is probably: [numpy array concatenate: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989950/numpy-array-concatenate-valueerror-all-the-input-arrays-must-have-same-number)

I am getting stucked with my function `numpy.append`. Here you can find the [docs](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.append.html).

My two arrays are:

```
X_p3 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [3,3]])
y_3 = np.array([[1], [1],[1]])
```

[image]

With shapes: `X_p3 (3,2)`and `y_3 (3,1)`.

If I run: `np.append(X_p3, y_3, axis=0)`

I receive the error:

> ValueError: all the input array dimensions except for the concatenation axis must match exactly

I already tried: `np.append(X_p3, y_3.reshape(len(y_3), 2), axis=0)` , but this also gives another error. How can I fix this?

Comment: Why not use concatenate as suggested in linked one - `np.concatenate((X_p3,y_3),axis=1)`?

Comment: please mark it as duplicate, thx

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In my humble opinion, you would probably be better off using `numpy.concatenate` given that calling `numpy.append` actually calls `numpy.concatenate`.

What you would have to do to solve your problem would be:

```
import numpy as np

np.concatenate([X_p3, y_3], axis=1)

# > array([[1, 2, 1],
# >        [3, 4, 1],
# >        [3, 3, 1]])
```

---

For reference, the [source code](https://github.com/numpy/numpy/blob/v1.17.0/numpy/lib/function_base.py#L4647-L4700) of `numpy.append` is as such:

```
def append(arr, values, axis=None):
    arr = asanyarray(arr)
    if axis is None:
        if arr.ndim != 1:
            arr = arr.ravel()
        values = ravel(values)
        axis = arr.ndim-1
    return concatenate((arr, values), axis=axis)
```

Answer (score 1):

try the below one,

```
import numpy as np
X_p3 = np.array([[1,2], [3,4], [3,3]])
y_3 = np.array([[1], [1],[1]])

concatenate=np.concatenate([X_p3,y_3],axis=1)
print(concatenate)

output:
      [[1 2 1]
      [3 4 1]
      [3 3 1]]
```

Comment: while concatenate axis=0 means row and axis=1 means column.