# Numpy array concatenate: ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly

Tags: python, numpy

How to concatenate these NumPy arrays?

first array with a shape (3951, 400)
second array with a shape (4939, 4)

I tried `np.concatenate((array1, array2), axis=1)`
and I tried another solution like in this question  [numpy array concatenate: "ValueError: all the input arrays must have same number of dimensions"](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41989950/numpy-array-concatenate-valueerror-all-the-input-arrays-must-have-same-number) but I get this error

ValueError: all the input array dimensions for the concatenation axis must match exactly, but along dimension 0, the array at index 0 has size 3951 and the array at index 1 has size 4939

Comment: To concatenate, arrays must be the same shape, except in the axis you specified. See: https://numpy.org/doc/stable/reference/generated/numpy.concatenate.html

Comment: okay, but i need to concatenate all axis1

Comment: You will have to reshape one of the two arrays

Comment: With those dimensions, `concatenate` does not make sense.  What exactly do you expect - specify the shape and dtype.

Comment: @hpaulj, I want a new array with a shape (8890,404), what I will do?

Comment: @kabooya,I want a new array with a shape (8890,404), what I will do?